# Combine cloned UL menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am cloning UL's from one element to another like so.

```
    $( "#mobMenu li a" ).each(function(index) {

     var subID = $(this).attr('id') 

      if (typeof(subID) !== "undefined") {
          subID = "#sub_" + subID + " .subnav-menu"
           var subMenu = $(subID).clone();
           $(this).parent().append(subMenu);
    }
});
```

Menu I am cloning:

```
<div id="sub_cat3">

 <ul id="sub_cat" class="subnav-menu">
   <li>..</li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="subnav-menu">
   <li>..</li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Into a new mobile menu that looks like this:

```
<ul id="mobMenu">
  <li><a id="cat3"></a>
 // cloned menu to go here
</li>
</ul>
```

So ho can I combine each cloned ul into one UL?

```
<ul class="subnav-menu">
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sample HTML would help a lot (perhaps in an SO snippet or a JSFiddle?)

Comment: updated with clearer html

Comment: Answer updated below to use your new HTML (no code change needed): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b10n5mf0/2/ Luckily I guessed your structure correctly :)

Comment: +1 now you have added usable HTML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want something like this (had to contrive the HTML as a suitable example was not provided):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b10n5mf0/1/

or with your new HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/b10n5mf0/4/

```
$("#mobMenu li a").each(function (index) {
    var subID = $(this).attr('id')
    console.log(subID);
    if (subID) {
        subID = "#sub_" + subID + " .subnav-menu li"
        var $div = $('<ul>').append($(subID).clone());
        $(this).closest('li').append($div);
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

- It creates a single UL for each matching set of lists' LIs.
- Only the matching LIs are cloned, then inserted under the created UL with `append`.
- `if (typeof(subID) !== "undefined")` can be replaced with `if (subID)` as `attr` returns a string or undefined (and empty strings are treated as undefined by your code).

Comment: Obviously calling a `UL` variable `$div` was a mistake (habit appending divs). `var $ul` would be nicer :)

Comment: how would I clone instead on inserting via html?

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
var $subs = $('.subnav-menu'),
    $lis = $subs.find('> li').clone();

// Add all the $lis to the first subnav...
$subs.eq(0).append($lis);

// Remove the rest of the subs...
$subs.slice(1).remove();
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/jerapo/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Now I am just confused.